# Pass multiple value by AJAX to PHP script

Tags: php, ajax

I cannot understand why I cannot receive my post value in php script

```js
var itemNameMinus = wrapperMinus.find('.Pname').text();
alert('The itemName = '+ itemNameMinus + "and Quantety = " + quantetyMinus);
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    datatype: 'json',
    url: 'addToBasket.php',
    data: {quantety: quantatyNumber, itemName: itemNameMinus},
    seccess: function(){}
});
```

php script:

```php
if(isset($_POST['quantety'], $_POST['itemName'])){
    echo 'test';
    echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$_POST['quantety']. "''".$_POST['itemNAme']."');</script>");

}
```

Comment: Have you checked ```var_dump($_POST)``` ?

Comment: How are you checking to see that they _aren't_ being received?  You are telling your ajax method to expect JSON as a response, but then you aren't sending JSON back.  That will cause your ajax to fail.  So unless you are checking the raw response in your browser's network inspector, then you're not going to get the response you expect.

Comment: I tried to remove "datatype: 'json'" and var_dump I get nothing in console.log. I ma new in php and AJAX. if you can help my to fix my problem then it would be great

Comment: You wouldn't see anything in your Javascript console because you're not logging anything to it.  As mentioned, check your network inspector to see the raw response.

Comment: Thanks. In my raw response I can see both value that was passed to php. It working, but why I cannot see it in console.log

Comment: Because, as I said, you're not actually logging anything.  You have to explicitly do something with the response.  I suggest you do some research on executing Javascript from the response body within the ajax callback handler.  FYI, the callback name you want is "success", not "seccess".

Comment: @PatrickQ thank you Patrick. Well the best way is to look into network inspector.

Comment: Don't make PHP echo a script tag and command. That will not be executed (in an Ajax context). Instead PHP should just echo the values (maybe as a JSON object, it's a very convenient format for outputting multiple values). Then in the "success" callback in your client-side code, that's where you can read the values which PHP has returned to you and then log them or output them on the page, whatever you need to do. The issue you've got here appears to be output, not input